# How to select a color from a Matplotlib gradient

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, colors, gradient

I would like to display elements colored according to a specific value (I am developping with FreeCAD) and then to plot a legend with matplotlib as a color bar.
I manage to create a color bar going from the minimum to the maximum of my list of values but then I don't know how to set colors for each value of the list:

- 10 --> red
- 0  --> green
- 2.3 --> ?

For now my code is like this:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

figure = plt.figure()
canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)

val_max= 10
val_min= 0

ax = figure.add_axes([0.05, 0.10, 0.5, 0.8])
cmap = mpl.cm.RdYlGn.reversed()
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=val_min, vmax=val_max)
ticks_cm = np.linspace(val_min, val_max, 10, endpoint=True)
cb1 = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(ax, cmap=cmap,
                           norm=norm,
                           ticks=ticks_cm,
                           orientation='vertical')
canvas.draw()
```

[colorBar ploted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjHJg.png)

I would be glad to know if it is possible to retrieve a color from this gradient, associated to a value which is between my min and max. Thx

Answer (score 1):

`cmap(norm(val))` will return the RGBA value associated with value `val` (in the interval `[val_min, val_max]`)

```
val_max= 10
val_min= 0

cmap = mpl.cm.RdYlGn.reversed()
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=val_min, vmax=val_max)

print(cmap(norm(5)))

> (0.9999231064975009, 0.9976163014225298, 0.7450211457131872, 1.0)
```